# Fill the remaining space with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following html ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/nhhzw29p/3/)):

```
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <label>Simple label
      <input>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Other label
      <input>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Variable label
      <input>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible with CSS (I don't want to use JavaScript for this), to fill the remaining space with the inputs? I have variable label length, and I want to align the right side of the input's without `float: right` (but not to bother also the left alignment).

Comment: `input { width: 100% }`?

Comment: I want the label and the input in a single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `label` a `flex` parent and set the `input` to `flex-grow: 1`

```css
#container div {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 300px;
}

input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

label {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <label>Simple label
      <input>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Other label
      <input>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Variable label
      <input>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```